# Blinking ggplot in shiny R app

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm doing a small shiny app that only has one ggplot that is updated every couple of seconds. It works, but the blinking is a bit annoying. I wonder if anyone has an idea about how to smooth it out. Example:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {


    output$showplot <- renderPlot({
        grid <- expand.grid(1:3,1:3)
        nums <- rbinom(9,1,0.5)
        g <- ggplot(grid,aes(Var1,Var2)) + 
            geom_tile(aes(fill = nums),colour="black") +
            guides(fill = FALSE) +
            theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) + 
            theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(), axis.text.y=element_blank(), axis.ticks.y=element_blank()) + 
            theme(aspect.ratio=1)

        print(g)

        invalidateLater(1000,session)
   })

})

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(

        ),

    mainPanel(
        h5("Plot blinking"),
        plotOutput("showplot")
    )
)
))

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

I should add that while looking around for a similar question, the solution provided was adding

```
tags$style(type="text/css",
    ".recalculating {opacity: 1.0;}" ),
```

as the first item in FluidPage. This doesn't seem to work for my case.

Comment: Which operating system and web browser are you using?  I don't see any "blinking" in the plot on a Debian 8 machine in RStudio 0.99.491, Chrome 52.0.2743.116, or Firefox ESR 45.3.0.  (R 3.31, ggplot2_2.2.1, shiny_0.13.0)

Comment: Ah I didn't think about that.  WIndows 10, Firefox 48.0, ggplot2_2.1.0 shiny_0.12.2, R version 3.2.2. It blinks in firefox but not in Chrome 52.0.2743.116. Hmn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have alook at this: I had the same problem and it was solved [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1591):